# How to use multiple condition in one foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Can I do this- "foreach($products as $product && $categories as $category)". multiple condition in one foreach loop? If not then how do I proceed this?

Comment: ye can not do that

Comment: Um... what exactly are you trying to achieve? foreach is a looping mechanism around a single array, not a condition statement.

Comment: I can't understand why do people answer that question with wired solutions, instead of closing it - Condition? foreach? what are you talking about?

Comment: No, you can't use loop in that way but there are many other ways to get the solution of your problem. Don't restrict yourself on that, you know the nature of your application and your problem so you can solve that in many other way. Or describe your problem , will find out more solutions of that.

Answer (score 1):

Use two loops:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      //  using $product and $category
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something dirrent to what OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt You're entirely guessing what the OP wants, since the question doesn't make sense. Imo this is currently seeming like the more likely candidate.

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt What is it that OP wants to accomplish?

Comment: Well, to me it sounds and looks more like he has two arrays and wants to work on both using the same loop and not iterating over the first array and then doing a loop over all items of the second array for each element of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question today as the OP. I figured I can split up the problem by first merging the two arrays and then performing the actual foreach loop on the combined array.

This is the idea:

```
$combined_array = $products + $categories

foreach ($combined_array as $items) {. . .}
```

Practically speaking, I split the problem into two foreach loops, the first for the merging of the arrays and the second for the actual algorithm.
And indeed it does save me alot of space! Since it is much shorter to append one array to another array than to repeat a complicated foreach algorithm on two separate arrays consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

If your two arrays have the same length, just use a for loop instead and access the elements using the current index.
You just have to make sure, that the indezies are matching in the two arrays.
Its not possible to achieve what you are trying using a foreach loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
    // do whatever you want with $arr1[$i] and $arr2[$i]
}
```

If your array have the same length, but the indizies may differ and you still want them to be on par, use `array_values()` before the loop to reindex both arrays.

This will only work for index based arrays!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that.
but what can you do is to loop inside the loop

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
   foreach($products as $product)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

foreach( $codes as $code and $names as $name ) { }
That is not valid.

You probably want something like this...

```
foreach( $codes as $index => $code ) {
   echo '<option value="' . $code . '">' . $names[$index] . '</option>';
}
```